AWS Lambda - Invalid request, no body found problem
I am trying to create Lambda function with the usage of API Gateway. I used CORS with OPTIONS (which have the correct methods) and I uploaded my zip file to the lambda. I coudln't find the fix of this error after multiple uplods. I hope you can help me to figure it out.
Here are the structure


Index.js
const { DynamoDBClient, QueryCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const client = new DynamoDBClient({ region: process.env.AWS_REGION });

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  console.log("Received event:", JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));

  if (!event.body) {
    return {
      statusCode: 400,
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET,PUT,DELETE",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type,Authorization,X-Amz-Date,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ error: "Invalid request, no body found" }),
    };
  }

  const { username, password } = JSON.parse(event.body);

  const params = {
    TableName: "users",
    IndexName: "username-index",
    KeyConditionExpression: "username = :username",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":username": { S: username },
    },
  };

  try {
    const command = new QueryCommand(params);
    const result = await client.send(command);
    if (result.Items.length === 0) {
      console.log("No user found with username:", username);
      return {
        statusCode: 400,
        headers: {
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET,PUT,DELETE",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type,Authorization,X-Amz-Date,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ message: "Invalid credentials" }),
      };
    }

    const user = result.Items[0];
    console.log("User found:", user);

    const isPasswordValid = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password.S);
    console.log("Password is valid:", isPasswordValid);

    if (!isPasswordValid) {
      console.log("Invalid password for username:", username);
      return {
        statusCode: 400,
        headers: {
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET,PUT,DELETE",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type,Authorization,X-Amz-Date,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ message: "Invalid credentials" }),
      };
    }

    const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user.userId.S }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
      expiresIn: "1h",
    });
    console.log("Generated token:", token);

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET,PUT,DELETE",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type,Authorization,X-Amz-Date,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ token }),
    };
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.error("Login error:", error);
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET,PUT,DELETE",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type,Authorization,X-Amz-Date,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ error: "Could not log in user" }),
    };
  }
};

The error:
Login response: 
{data: {…}, status: 200, statusText: '', headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
Login.js:21 Login response data: 
{statusCode: 400, headers: {…}, body: '{"error":"Invalid request, no body found"}'}
body
: 
"{\"error\":\"Invalid request, no body found\"}"
headers
: 
{Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*', Access-Control-Allow-Methods: 'OPTIONS,POST,GET,PUT,DELETE', Access-Control-Allow-Headers: 'Content-Type,Authorization,X-Amz-Date,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'}
statusCode
: 
400
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object

package.json
{
  "name": "my-lambda-function",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb": "^3.587.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2"
  }
}

I also add mapping template to my POST resourece in auth/login/ at API Gateway as:
{
  "body": $input.json('$')
}

As last, here is my Login.js to make you understand how I handle the request.
Login.js
  const handleLogin = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    setError("");
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        "/auth/login",
        JSON.stringify({ username, password }), // Ensure body is a JSON string
        { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } }
      );
      console.log("Login response:", response);
      console.log("Login response data:", response.data);
      if (response.data.token) {
        localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token);
        onAuthSuccess();
      } else {
        setError("Invalid credentials");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Login error:", error);
      setError("Invalid credentials");
    }
    setLoading(false);
  };


I made it working, after some modifications
mapping template to my POST resourece in auth/login/ at API Gateway as:
{
  "body": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.body)"
}

I also needed to add policy to a role which is loginUser-role-8nvnlq44
The policy is:
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "dynamodb:Query",
        "dynamodb:PutItem",
        "dynamodb:UpdateItem",
        "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
        "dynamodb:GetItem"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-north-1:637423521822:table/users",
        "arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-north-1:637423521822:table/users/index/username-index"
      ]
    }
  ]
}


You can replace your 2-liner resource with a single line. arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-north-1:637423521822:table/users*. By doing so, any indices added in the future will even be supported.

Thanks for the recomendation I will check it out
